# How to add Year view in jquery fullcalender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am facing some issue. I need to display the yearview in my fullcalender of Jquery plugin. I am explaining my code below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                eventClick:function (event, jsEvent) {
                  scope.popArr='';
                  var date=event.start._i;
                  var auditData=$.param({'date':date});
                  $http({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:'php/myworkspesh.php?action=getAllAuditDataAsPerDay',
                    data:auditData,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                  }).then(function successCallback(response){
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        scope.popArr=response.data;
                        $('#auditpopup').modal({
                          backdrop: 'static'
                        });
                    }
                  },function errorCallback(response) {
                  })
                },
                eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                    var evStart = moment(view.intervalStart).subtract(1, 'days');
                    var evEnd = moment(view.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'days');
                    if (!event.start.isAfter(evStart) ||
                        event.start.isAfter(evEnd)) { return false; }
                },
                defaultDate: todayDate,
                navLinks: true, 
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: evtArr
            });
```

Here I need to add the year view and this fullcalender version is `3.4.0`.

Comment: Don't think there is a year view. Not really clear what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @charlietfl : Here like `month,agendaWeek,agendaDay` some type views are there similarly I need calender view in year wise like `month` here.

Comment: Create 12 calendars then

Comment: Do you want to display only years instead on month and date?

Comment: why  12 calender ? I think when user will click on the year link all month of one year will display there.

Comment: @Chidambaram : Yes I need also the years along with month view. There should be two options.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/

Comment: @Chidambaram : Is this a fullcalender view ?

Comment: No this displays year and month in ddl. Do you want month names displayed in the place of date in normal datepicker? like showing year on top and month in picker grid? Then here you go http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160769/discussion-between-subhra-and-chidambaram).

Comment: Your possible options for achieving this, or something close to it, are outlined here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ - to change the visible dates on an agenda or list-style view, or write a whole custom view from scratch, which is hard. But consider the wisdom of your request - if you display all the months, realistically if you have more than 3 or 4 events in each month it won't be possible to display them all properly. Unless your calendar is quite empty this will not be a very useful view I don't think. Why not just let the user choose a month they want to see in detail?

Comment: @ADyson : Can you recommend some other type full calender which must have year,month type view and inside each cell I should have title,event etc ?

Comment: I don't know of anything no, but you can use google just as well as me, I'm sure. But you didn't answer my question about why you want to do this. Is it really going to be a good idea, given the large span of time it covers and the possibility for so many events to be shown that it's un-readable? Like I said, why can't the user just choose the month and year from another control, like a datepicker or something? I'm just trying to see whether you really _need_ to do this, since it's giving you trouble. Maybe another kind of UI would meet the requirement.

Comment: Ok, I will try your idea and let you know.